# Get last message from text channel with discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I feel like all my research on this topic lead me only to outdated solutions.

With my Discord.js bot, I have a command. For it to work I need to get the last message in a channel right before the command. I am struggling with all those fetches and partials and cache etc.

Sometimes it works when I post the message right after my bot started and use the command on it, but if I restart my bot it seems to get the wrong message. Also, what about messages that are older than 14 days?

I can't really provide code because it's just one line, like:

`const message = msg.channel.messages. ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`message.channel.messages` returns a  [manager of the messages](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager) sent to this channel. To get the last one, you can use its [`fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch) method with the [query option](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ChannelLogsQueryOptions) `{limit: 1}`. It means, you can fetch the last message in a channel using `message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 1 })`. However, if you run this fetch after you sent a command, the last message will be the one with that command.

To solve this, you can fetch the last two messages in the channel by increasing the limit: `message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 2 })`. The fetched collection will contain the command (you used to fetch the last message) and the message right before that.

Discord collections have a [`.last()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=last) method that obtains the last value, so you can now grab the last message by using this:

```js
const messages = await message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 2 });
const lastMessage = messages.last();

console.log(lastMessage.content);
```

[image]

PS.: It has no problem with fetching messages older than 14 days.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [this](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=messages) and use messages#fetch to fetch non-cached messages!

Hope this helps :)